# Turning off assertion fail comments

Tags: system-verilog, uvm, system-verilog-assertions

I'm writing assertions to detect a particular sequence occurrence. In case the sequence is not not true, I get prints in log for assertion failure. But I just want to check if sequence occurred or not. Is there any way to turn of these prints?

FYI: there is no `uvm_error` or `uvm_fatal` in the `else` part of the assertion

Comment: it depends on how you write assertions, and which tool you use.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `cover` directive in this case, not an `assert`. A `cover` directive only has a pass action and no fail action.

If you had used an `else` clause in your assertion, you could have used `$assertfailoff`

Comment: The cover directive works in this case. Thanks!
As for the $assertfailoff, I'm getting unknown system call or function. Just wanted to confirm if it's not supported in vcs (Version-2018) or am I doing something wrong

Comment: See section _20.12 Assertion control system tasks_ in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595). It's a shortcut for `$assertcontrol(9, 31, 7, levels [,list])`